How to get Sharepoint and ms365 groups of a sharepoint file
I am trying to get all groups that have access to a given sharepoint file. I need the sharepoint groups + the ms365 groups that have at least read access but I only get the sharepoint groups.
I use the msgraph api to get the permissions
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/permissions
Here in gratend_to_v2 are only the sharepoint groups.
How can I find out which ms365 groups have access to this file? I do not find anything about this in the documentations.
